# swift photo reveal timer set up

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a photo reveal quiz piece to a larger app that I'm creating. The picture of the set up looks like this so far(rough draft so to speak)
[image: screen shot of set up so far]

The 16 labeled items are there just to give a sense of the end product(they will be white tiles in the app). How can I program it so that they begin disappearing when they user taps reveal picture? `NSTimer`? Should they be labels or `UIView`s or ?? Thanks for any hints.

I can get this far, but would want to add code to make the tiles disappear randomly and roughly each second

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var gameTimer : NSTimer!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var tile15: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tile16: UIView!

@IBOutlet var photoTilesHandler: [UIView]!
//@IBOutlet weak var viewTile: UIView!
//@IBOutlet var pictureTiles: [UILabel]!
@IBOutlet var buttonHandler: [UIButton]!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func revealButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    Hide()
    print("button pressed")

}


func Hide() {
        var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tile15.hidden = true
        })
    }


override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    gameTimer.invalidate()
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your `UILabels`/`UIViews`/`etc` in an `IBOutletCollection`. Then inside of `dispatch_after`'s callback do the following steps:

0.- You might want to keep track of which tiles are already *facedown*. So this way you can know at every time which index you have already used and pick always new ones.

> One way to achieve this is storing the full list of indexes available to select and instead of taking into account your `IBOutletCollection` for the following steps take as reference your unused indexes list and, after you randomly pick one, remove it from the list.

1.- Determine a/(a set of) random integers between 0...[your `IBOutletCollection`].length - 1]

2.- Use this numbers as an index to set the `hidden` property of [your `IBOutletCollection`] corresponding element to `true`

As your other question, my recommendation would be to use `UIViews`  with your `UILabel` inside or `UIButtons`. The tap zone of labels is a bit hard to use.

Comment: thanks for the note. I noticed when I connected all the labels to the IBCollection, when I reference the collection in the function, the .alpha and .hidden methods are not available? I have tried .removelast, and a fwe others, but nothing appears to happen.

Comment: You can change the type of your collection and it will still work properly, or just cast the items when needed to the type you are using.

Comment: For example: if you use `@IBOutlet var items: [UIButton]!` when you call `self.items[0].hidden = true` works like charm.